# How to Display Grid Item In Different Different Size In windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to display image in gird in different different size in windows phone application. like following image format in windows phone application

Thanx

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Rectangles are added to simulate the screenshot you put - you'll use the controls you need. I explicitly set the Grid.Row and Grid.Column to 0 to emphasize what's happening.